# Error in using sparql DELETE query using rdflib python

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I am trying to DELETE triples from RDF graph using rdflib library of python, but not succeeding in doing so. My query is the follwong learned from http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#delete .

```
plugin.register(
    'sparql', rdflib.query.Processor,
    'rdfextras.sparql.processor', 'Processor')
plugin.register(
    'sparql', rdflib.query.Result,
    'rdfextras.sparql.query', 'SPARQLQueryResult')

bdel= graph.query(""" 
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>                       
DELETE  {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE { 
         ?s bibo:reproducedIn ?o. 
      }""")
```

It is giving following error, any clue to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "SELECT" (at char 116), (line:4, col:17)
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, it looks like you are trying to use `graph.query` which does indeed expect only 'SELECT' versions of SPARQL Queries.  In order to run any SPARQL Updates [as defined here](http://www.w3.org/Submission/SPARQL-Update/), you will need to use `graph.processUpdate()` instead.
For your example, something along the lines of:

```
processUpdate(graph, """ 
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>                       
DELETE  {?s ?p ?o}
WHERE { 
?s bibo:reproducedIn ?o. 
}""")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFLib#SPARQL_querying) ! tested it through code too ! the version of rdflib i am using is 5.0.0

Answer (score 2):

The query you are using is a [SPARQL Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#delete), which is a distinct standard from [SPARQL Query](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/).
Possibly the `graph.query` function expects only SPARQL Query? I can't see any mention of Sparql Update on the relevant [rdflib pages](https://rdfextras.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Looking at [this page](https://github.com/gromgull/rdflib-sparql), it looks like you may need to use the `processUpdate()` method of `rdflib-sparql` instead?

The [online validator](http://www.sparql.org/validate/query) agrees that this is not a valid *SPARQL Query* (though it looks like valid *SPARQL Update* to me)